# How to reset memory usage of GPU when training model on server

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, nvidia

I am training an LSTM model, but the time taking by one epoch is too high. And if I check the memory usage by using nvidia-smi, I get the following where all the available memory is assigned.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   38C    P0    58W / 250W |  15967MiB / 16280MiB |     71%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla P100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:82:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   30C    P0    25W / 250W |      0MiB / 16280MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A     10871      C   ...tify/aidentify/bin/python    15965MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried to kill the process with PID ID, but then kernel restarts and if I start training the model again, it uses all the memory and the training is slow again.
Warning I get when I use "tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array"

```
I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1613] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 15389 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 6.0
```

Is it possible to reset the memory usage or is it possible to run on other GPU1 which is available. Kindly help to resolve this issue.

Comment: TensorFlow by default allocates all GPU RAM and manages it by itself. So that is not a problem by itself.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy but my training is too slow, how can I overcome this problem ?

Comment: Then you should ask about that problem, this question is about memory use. Typical XY problem.